# How can I convert integer to qbitarray?

Tags: qt

How can I get QBitArray from qint value? I need to change some bits in number, so I want to use QBitArray for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QBitArray's '>>' operator expects bitset size as the first 4 bytes, so JustMaximumPower's snipper won't work. Correct data stream should look like this:

```
QBitArray bits;

quint32 size = 32;
quint32 value = 1337;
QByteArray data;
QDataStream stream(data, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
stream << size << value;
stream.device()->seek(0);
stream >> bits;
```

Actually I don't find QBitArray very useful. You could try std::vector<bool> for variable size or std::bitset for fixed size (both from STL library).

```
std::bitset<32> bits(1337);
bits[0] = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it was helpful. Actually I needed QBitArray because of requirements of my work at the university.

Answer (score 0):

Not testet but should work:

```
qint value = 1337;
QBitArray bits;
QDataStream stream;

stream << value;
bits << stream;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to just change some bits, `QBitArray` is overkill.

```
int bitmask = 1 << 3; // let's change 4th bit
bitmask = 0x55555555; // or perhaps all odd bits

int number = 12345678;
number |= bitmask; // set to 1s
number &= ~bitmask; // set to 0s
number ^= bitmask; // negate what's already there
```